# Stuck in a Loop. Directory Listing using Excel VBA

Tags: vba, loops, excel, filesystemobject

I'm trying to make a directory listing of my drive here with the directories, subdirectories/folders, and files included. It also shows the file name, file path, date, and size. 
I'm currently using this code:

```
Dim iRow

Sub ListFiles()
    iRow = 11 'starting row listing
    Call ListMyFiles(Range("B5"), Range("B6"))
End Sub

Sub ListMyFiles(mySourcePath, IncludeSubfolders)
    Set MyObject = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Set mySource = MyObject.GetFolder(mySourcePath)
        On Error Resume Next
        For Each myFile In mySource.Files
        iCol = 3
        Cells(iRow, iCol).Value = myFile.Path
        iCol = iCol + 1
        Cells(iRow, iCol).Value = myFile.Name
        iCol = iCol + 1
        Cells(iRow, iCol).Value = myFile.Size
        iCol = iCol + 1
        Cells(iRow, iCol).Value = myFile.DateLastModified
        iRow = iRow + 1
    Next
    If IncludeSubfolders Then
        For Each mySubFolder In mySource.SubFolders
            Call ListMyFiles(mySource.Path, True)
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Whenever I input an address it works fine, but when I decide to include the subfolders, it goes into haywire! It just loops on and on forever. It just does not stop.
I don't know where to look for the error. I keep on rereading it and it seems okay, but maybe that's just me. Also, I ticked the Microsoft Scripting Runtime, for the record.
And also, I think I still lack something here because I also wanted to show the Folder Names as well, if that is possible.

This question may not be clear or may be already duplicated, so let me know. Thank you!

P.S.
Kind of a newbie here.

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22645347/loop-through-all-subfolders-using-vba

Comment: should `Call ListMyFiles(mySource.Path, True)` be `Call ListMyFiles(mySubFolder.Path, True)`  for the subfolders

Comment: Oh. Oh right! It worked. I didn't notice that one. Forever looping stopped. Thanks.

Comment: @SearchAndResQ Put this as an answer, not as a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path value that is being passed to the function for the sub folder listing is wrong.

It should be:

`Call ListMyFiles(mySubFolder.Path, True)`