# Loop through excel rows and call VBA functions

Tags: vba, excel

I need to be able to loop through my rows (specifically, column B), and use the number in a certain cell in order to do specific functions using other cells in that row. For example, Rule #1 indicates that I need to find last modified date of the path in the cell next to the Rule #, but the task is different for each Rule.

I'm new to VBA and I've just been struggling with setting up a loop and passing variables to different subs, and would hugely appreciate any help. To be clear, I'm looking for syntax help with the loop and passing variables

Thank you!

Reference Images: [The spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F0u6X.png)

[The attempt at sketching out the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JoCFZ.png)

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim x As Integer
    NumRows = Range("B2", Range("B2").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
    Range("B2").Select
    For x = 1 To NumRows
        If Range(RowCount, 1).Value = 1 Then
             RuleOne (RowCount)
        End If
    Next

    'Dim RowCount As Integer
    'RowCount = 1
    'Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, 2) = Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Row.Count

    'While RowCount < Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows
      'If Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(RowCount, 1).Value = 1 Then
          'RuleOne (RowCount)
      'End If
    'Wend
End Sub

Sub RuleOne(i As Integer)
    'use filedatetime and path from i cell
    'Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, 1) = FileDateTime(C, i)
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, 1) = "hello"
End Sub

Sub RuleTwo(i As Integer)
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, 1) = "hello"
End Sub
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include code in the body of question and not as a snapshot.

Comment: Are you getting errors? If so, try taking the parenthesis away from the variables you pass to the function. `RuleOne RowCount`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22645347/loop-through-all-subfolders-using-vba

Comment: Got it, thanks @skkakkar!

Comment: @Nathan_Sav that question is quite different in that it is trying to loop through subfolders in a folder, but I really appreciate it.

Comment: @BruceWayne the first error I'm getting is presumably very simple, it's with the line: If Range(RowCount, 1).Value = 1 Then

Comment: Sorry, I copied the wrong link, but from the File System Object you can get the created and last modified dates.

Comment: You never set `RowCount` as a variable. That's why you're getting an error.  Do you mean `NumRows`??  Also, I'd add `Option Explicit` above `Private Sub ...` to force declaration of all variables, this could have helped catch `RowCount` wasn't declared.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the `Range(RowCount, 1).Value = 1` to `Cells(x, 2).Value = 1`.

Answer (score 0):

The variable RowCount has not been initialised/set.
I assume this is what this variable is meant to be the number in column B

```
RowCount = Cells(x, "B").Value
```

I also noticed that the variable NumRows seemed to be one less than it should be (so if the last row was 1 it would skip it). So I used this instead:

```
NumRows = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
```

So try this code:

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim x As Integer
    NumRows = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    For x = 1 To NumRows
        RowCount = Range("B" & x).Value
        If RowCount = 1 Then
             RuleOne (x)
        End If
    Next

    'Dim RowCount As Integer
    'RowCount = 1
    'Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, 2) = Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Row.Count

    'While RowCount < Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows
      'If Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(RowCount, 1).Value = 1 Then
          'RuleOne (RowCount)
      'End If
    'Wend
End Sub

Sub RuleOne(i As Integer)
    'use filedatetime and path from i cell
    'Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, 1) = FileDateTime(C, i)
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, i) = "hello"
End Sub

Sub RuleTwo(i As Integer)
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, 1) = "hello"
End Sub
```