# List all worksheets in workbooks stored in various folders and subfolders- Excel, VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have been trying to write a macro that will list the sheet names of every workbook in my directory. These files are stored in various folders and subfolders, so I would like for it to pull out everything and I can extrapolate the information I need from the whole output. This code is something I've put together with the help of users from this site, but I still am not getting the desired result. Someone please help!

```
Sub machinegun()
    FileType = "*.xls*"
    OutputRow = 2
 Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
 Set Folder = fso.GetFolder("G:")
 Set Curr_File = (filepath & FileType)
 For Each Subfolder In Folder.Subfolders
    Do Until Curr_File = ""
        Set Fldr.wkbk = Workbooks.Open(filepath & Curr_File, False, True)
        ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A" & OutputRow) = Curr_File
        ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("B" & OutputRow).ClearContents
        OutputRow = OutputRow + 1

        For Each Sht In FldrWkbk.Sheets
            ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("B" & OutputRow) = Sht.Name
            ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A" & OutputRow).ClearContents
            OutputRow = OutputRow + 1
        Next Sht
        FldrWkbk.Close SaveChanges:=False
      Loop
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: The looks like it should do what you need it to do.  Are you able to specify what it is that you're not happy with?

Comment: I guess my initial complaint would be that it does not yield any results... I had a version of the code that could do one folder at a time, but I need it to do nearly 400 and that's just not sustainable.

Comment: Sorry, The way I read your question, it didn't sound that serious.  I see now that you're not looping through the files and subfolders properly so hopefully Vityata's answer get that part sorted.

Answer (score 1):

Here is something from [Loop Through All Subfolders Using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22645347/loop-through-all-subfolders-using-vba), that would work for you:

```
Option Explicit

Sub LoopThroughFiles()

    Dim FileSystem As Object
    Dim HostFolder As String

    HostFolder = "C:\Users\"

    Set FileSystem = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    DoFolder FileSystem.GetFolder(HostFolder)

End Sub


Sub DoFolder(Folder)

    Dim SubFolder

    For Each SubFolder In Folder.SubFolders
        DoFolder SubFolder
    Next
    Dim File
    For Each File In Folder.Files
        Debug.Print File.name
    Next

End Sub
```

Just make sure that you run `LoopThroughFiles()` and change the `HostFolder` to something meaningful. Then work with `File.name` in the `debug.print`.