# How can I store multiple selected file paths in an array from a for loop?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to take the file path using the

```
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
        'Makes sure the user can select only one file
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        'Filter to just the following types of files to narrow down selection options
        .Filters.Add "Excel Files", "*.xlsx; *.xlsm; *.xls; *.xlsb", 1
        'Show the dialog box
        .Show
        
        'Store in fullpath variable
        fullpath = .SelectedItems.Item(1)
    End With
```

And run this over a for loop until the user says they are finished and picked all the files they are looking for. I don't know how to store each file path in an array though because I want to run a search for multiple inputted phrases across each file and return an array with all the positive search results. (thinking nested loops) Suggestions?

Comment: Why do you need an array? That code only allows the user to select one file.

Comment: I want the search to run over multiple files but I want to select them one at a time so I thought I would store each file path in a list to run over them with the search loop

Comment: Refer [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44439638/change-file-names-within-subfolders-with-vba/44440788#44440788)

Comment: Since you don't know how many files the user will select, you will need to use a Do loop instead of a For loop.  Also, I would store the files in a Collection rather than an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code, please:

```
Sub PathsInAnArray()
  Dim FullPath As String, arrP, i As Long, elNo As Long
  
  elNo = 100 'use here a number bigger then your estimation about the maximum needed paths
  ReDim arrP(elNo)
  
  With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Filters.Add "Excel Files", "*.xlsx; *.xlsm; *.xls; *.xlsb", 1
        Do While .Show = -1
             FullPath = .SelectedItems.item(1)
             'in case of a wrong estimation of the necessary number of paths:
             If i = UBound(arrP) Then ReDim Preserve arrP(UBound(arrP) + elNo)
             arrP(i) = FullPath: i = i + 1
        Loop
    End With

    ReDim Preserve arrP(i - 1)
    'do whatever you need with the paths array...
    Debug.Print "There have been placed " & UBound(arrP) + 1 & " paths in ""arrP"" array..."
    Debug.Print arrP(0) 'first path in the array...
End Sub
```

It will end looping when you will press `Cancel` in the dialog window...

Comment: This works great. Since the array is being redefined when needed anyway, could I set the array size to 1 and it will increase as I select more?

Comment: @Shawn Malone: You can, but it is not good from memory handling, point of view. It is good to `Redim preserve` as rare as possible. That's why I added the line adding another set (in my example 100 elements) in case of reaching the array limit...

Comment: I see, thanks. Is there a way to make it save the selected items as workbooks instead? I am trying to search for a range in each book and it doesn't look like filepaths will accomplish that. I tried to change the FullPath to Workbook but it gives an error

Comment: I am driving now... I will telll something after some hours, when I will be at home.

Comment: Try declaring the array on top of the code module. In this way it will remain and can be used from other Subs...

Answer (score 1):

The combination of a Do loop and a Collection makes this easy to implement:

```
Private Sub GetFiles()
   Dim files As Collection
   Set files = New Collection

   With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
      .AllowMultiSelect = False
      .Filters.Add "Excel Files", "*.xlsx; *.xlsm; *.xls; *.xlsb", 1
      
      Do
         .Show
         If .SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then files.Add .SelectedItems.Item(1)
      Loop Until .SelectedItems.Count = 0

      'process the files as needed
   End With
End Sub
```