# VBA Macro to open/save/close workbooks in folder and subfolders

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

I have the following code that will open/save/close any/all workbooks in a folder. It works great, however, I also need it to include sub folders. The code needs to work without restrictions on the number of folders, sub folders and files, if possible.

I'm working with Excel 2010 and I'm new to VBA  - would really appreciate any help!

```
Sub File_Loop_Example()
    'Excel VBA code to loop through files in a folder with Excel VBA

    Dim MyFolder As String, MyFile As String

    'Opens a file dialog box for user to select a folder

    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
       .AllowMultiSelect = False
       .Show
       MyFolder = .SelectedItems(1)
       Err.Clear
    End With

    'stops screen updating, calculations, events, and statsu bar updates to help code run faster
    'you'll be opening and closing many files so this will prevent your screen from displaying that

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    'This section will loop through and open each file in the folder you selected
    'and then close that file before opening the next file

    MyFile = Dir(MyFolder & "\", vbReadOnly)

    Do While MyFile <> ""
        DoEvents
        On Error GoTo 0
        Workbooks.Open Filename:=MyFolder & "\" & MyFile, UpdateLinks:=False
        ActiveWorkbook.Save
        Workbooks(MyFile).Close SaveChanges:=True
        MyFile = Dir
    Loop

    'turns settings back on that you turned off before looping folders

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    MsgBox "Done!"

    End Sub
```

Comment: You can use: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22645347/loop-through-all-subfolders-using-vba

Comment: @Error1004 reply should give you your answer but please be aware of **recursive** UDF's. search for something like: **`recursive functions and its pitfalls`**

Comment: How would I incorporate the code in the @Error 1004 reply above? Or is it a case of incorporating my existing code into that? Apologies if this sounds dumb - I'm VERY new to this! Also, i would like to keep the folder picker that I have - would this be possible?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested, I found an alternative which I managed to adapt and does exactly what I want:

```
Sub Loop_Example()

Dim MyFolder As String
Dim file As Variant, wb As Excel.Workbook

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
       .AllowMultiSelect = False
       .Show
       MyFolder = .SelectedItems(1)
       Err.Clear
    End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For Each file In Filter(Split(CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Exec("CMD /C DIR """ & startFolder & "*.xl*"" /S /B /A:-D").StdOut.ReadAll, vbCrLf), ".")
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(file)
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    wb.Close SaveChanges:=True
    Set wb = Nothing
Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    MsgBox "Done!"

End Sub
```