# Editing multiple excel files which are in different folders all united in one folder

Tags: vba, excel, subdirectory

I have 200 folders all with different names in a folder. Now, each folder with a different name has a macro excel file (.xlsm). I'm trying to edit all the files at once with a separate file. The code goes like this:

```
Sub Button1_Click()

Dim wb      As Workbook
Dim ws      As Excel.Worksheet
Dim strPath As String
Dim strFile As String

'Get the directories
strPath = "C:\Users\generaluser\Desktop\testing main folder\"
strFile = Dir(strPath)

'Loop through the dirs
Do While strFile <> ""

    'Open the workbook.
    strFileName = Dir(strPath & strFile & "*.xlsm")
    'Open the workbook.
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=strPath & strFile & "\" & strFileName , ReadOnly:=False)

    'Loop through the sheets.

    Set ws = Application.Worksheets(1)

    'Do whatever
    ws.Range("A1").Interior.ColorIndex = 0



    'Close the workbook
    wb.Close SaveChanges:=True

    'Move to the next dir.
    strFile = Dir
Loop

End Sub
```

But this doesn't work. I have tried tweaking it but whatever i do either does nothing or causes an error. Can someone please help me get this code to work. 
(also: "testing main folder" is the folder on my desktop which holds the 200 other folders which hold the .xlsm files.)

Comment: [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22645347/loop-through-all-subfolders-using-vba) will help you understand how to loop through the subfolders.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cycle through sub-folders and files in a user-specified root directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14245712/cycle-through-sub-folders-and-files-in-a-user-specified-root-directory)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put `Option Explicit` at the top of the module.  You'll get some compiler errors, one of them being that `strFileName` isn't declared.  This *would* have been a great clue as to where to look, because the problem is that you're using two variable names that have roughly the same meaning when you read them, and they're getting mixed up.

After you're done fixing the variables, take a look at the documentation for the [Dir function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa262726(v=vs.60).aspx). The second issue is that you're also calling `Dir` multiple times in the loop, which means that you're skipping results.

It should look something more like this:

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
Dim file As String

'path never changes, so make it a Const
Const path = "C:\Users\generaluser\Desktop\testing main folder\"
'This returns the first result.
file = Dir$(path & "*.xlsm")

Do While file <> vbNullString
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=path & file, ReadOnly:=False)
    Set ws = Application.Worksheets(1)
    'Do whatever
    wb.Close SaveChanges:=True
    'This returns the next result, or vbNullString if none.
    file = Dir$
Loop
```

Comment: this still does not open the `.xlsm` files within the **subfolders**

Comment: @ScottHoltzman - I didn't see anything about subfolders in the question, but understanding how to iterate one directory is a certainly a step in the right direction.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman - Fair enough.  Dup of [Cycle through sub-folders and files in a user-specified root directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14245712/cycle-through-sub-folders-and-files-in-a-user-specified-root-directory) and voted to close.