# VBA Excel How to automatically compare multiple files to one master file then copy/paste the result

Tags: excel, vba

https://postimg.org/image/laeyoj9wn/ = List

[image]

https://postimg.org/image/ihlr4i9k7/ = Master list

[image]

I would like to compare the List and Master list serial number. If there is similarity value in serial number the serial number value will be automatically paste on the third column

```
Sub AutoUpdate()
Dim Dic As Object, key As Variant, oCell As Range, i&
Dim w1 As Worksheet, w2 As Worksheet

    Set Dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set w1 = Workbooks("Book1.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set w2 = Workbooks.Open("C:\UsersSurvey Testing\Book2.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set w3 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Survey Testing\Book3.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1")


    i = w2.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
    For Each oCell In w2.Range("A2:A" & i)
        If Not Dic.exists(oCell.Value) Then
            Dic.Add oCell.Value, oCell.Offset(, 0).Value
        End If

    Next
    i = w3.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
    For Each oCell In w3.Range("A2:A" & i)
        If Not Dic.exists(oCell.Value) Then
            Dic.Add oCell.Value, oCell.Offset(, 0).Value
        End If


    Next
    i = w1.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
    For Each oCell In w1.Range("A2:A" & i)
        For Each key In Dic
            If oCell.Value = key Then
                oCell.Offset(, 2).Value = Dic(key)
        End If


        Next
    Next

End Sub
```

Instead of setting the workbook 1 by 1 in the code, I would like to automatically find and set all the workbook in the folder and compare. Because there might be alot of workbook that need to be compare.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14245712/cycle-through-sub-folders-and-files-in-a-user-specified-root-directory). From that code, yours will look something like the following:

```
Sub Compare()
Dim Dic As Object
Dim fso As Object 'FileSystemObject
Dim fldStart As Object 'Folder
Dim fl As Object 'File
Dim Mask As String, i As Long
Dim Wbk As Workbook

Set fso = New FileSystemObject
Set fld = fso.GetFolder("C:\UsersSurvey Testing")

Set Dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

Mask = "*.xlsx"

For Each fl in fld.Files
    If fl.Name Like Mask Then
        Set Wbk = Workbooks.Open(fld & "\" & fl.Name).Sheets("Sheet1")
        i = Wbk.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
        For Each oCell In Wbk.Range("A2:A" & i)
            If Not Dic.exists(oCell.Value) Then
                Dic.Add oCell.Value, oCell.Offset(, 0).Value
            End If
        Next oCell
    End If
Next fl
End Sub
```

Note: I have not tested this code. It's just to get you an idea of what to try.

Comment: Thank you Alexis for the great solution. It is just what i needed. Apparently my VBA Excel 2007 doesn't read Set fso = New FileSystemObject yet only able to run if the code is this Set fso = CreateObject("scripting.FileSystemObject"). I wonder why, anyway thanks alot for the help appreciate it alot.

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually, this can be done completely without VBA, using Power Query, a free Microsoft add-in for Excel 2010 and 2013 and built into Excel 2013 as Get and Transform.

Open all files in a folder, append them, remove duplicates and save as master file.

When new files are added, refresh the query.

Comment: This isn't very robust in cases where files are added or removed from the folder. You can't just refresh the query; you'd need to append the new files and remove references to the old ones.

Comment: Wrong. It can be completely dynamic to open all files in a folder, not by name, but just all files. Ken Puls has a blog about that [here](http://www.excelguru.ca/blog/2015/02/25/combine-multiple-excel-workbooks-in-power-query/)

Comment: Oh wow, you're right. I had forgotten about the import From Folder button. The way you said "Open all files in folder" made it sound very manual in my mind.

Comment: Hey Teylyn, thanks alot for the great alternative solution. Good information for me to learn new stuff. Unfortunately, my boss just prefer the Macro VBA with just once click on the macro and everything runs itself. Thanks alot for the quick response! Appreciate it alot !