# VBA Excel recursive folder search stops

Tags: excel, vba, search, directory, fso

I have script to scan a folder for files with a file name containing a certain text. The script works but it stops after sometime without finishing the scan of the complete folder (I reached 16663 scans, is there a limit?). I can't figure out why the script stops. Any help is greatly appreciated.

I initially used the code posted in this post [Get list of sub-directories in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9827715/get-list-of-sub-directories-in-vba)

*Update: The drive I'm scanning is a network drive. My assumption now is that due to a hick-up in the connection the script stops. At the moment I'm trying different approaches to work around this...*

```
Sub LoopThroughFilePaths()

    Application.StatusBar = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Counter = 1

    Dim strPath As String
    strPath = "V:\50"                            ' folder to scan

    Dim myArr
    myArr = GetSubFolders(strPath)

    Application.StatusBar = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Used Function `GetSubFolders`

```
Function GetSubFolders(RootPath As String)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim fso As Object
    Dim fld As Object
    Dim sf As Object
    Dim myArr
    Dim output As String
    Dim StrFileOut As String
    VAR_01_output = "D:\output"                  'Location to copy found files to

    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set fld = fso.GetFolder(RootPath)

    Dim StrFile As String
    StrFile = Dir(fld + "\*labsuite*")           'wild card search for files

    Do While Len(StrFile) > 0
        StrFileOut = Format(Now(), "hh-mm-ss") & "_" & StrFile ' rename files
        FileCopy fld + "\" + StrFile, VAR_01_output + "\" + StrFileOut 'copy found files to output folder
        StrFile = Dir
    Loop

    For Each sf In fld.SubFolders
        ReDim Preserve Arr(Counter)
        Arr(Counter) = sf.Path
        Counter = Counter + 1

        On Error Resume Next
        myArr = GetSubFolders(sf.Path)
        On Error Resume Next

        'ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1).Value = Counter
        Application.StatusBar = sf.Path

        DoEvents
    Next

    GetSubFolders = Arr

    Set sf = Nothing
    Set fld = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing

End Function
```

Comment: How many files are in this folder? There shouldn't be a limit, but I'm surprised there are more than 16663 files in one folder

Comment: There are a lot of sub-folders and sub-sub-folders etc. containing a lot of files... Total nr. of files is probably +100000

Comment: Lol that's embarrassing, of course the count includes subfolders... *facepalm*

Comment: FWIW each call to `GetSubFolders` creates an new instance of `FileSystemObject`.  Don't do that,  rather create one and pass a reference to it to the recursive routine

Comment: [Here's a better method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14246818/445425)

Comment: @chrisneilsen I tried the method you posted, but I keep having the same problem...