# Is there a way to loop through (all) folders in a directory, pick out specific word documents, and convert to pdf using VBA?

Tags: vba, pdf, ms-word

I am very new too VBA and I am trying to automate converting word documents to pdf files. I have figured out how to convert all word documents within a single folder to pdf. Now I am struggling to apply that methodology to word documents across all subfolders in a directory. Is there a way to incorporate that in the code below? To add to it, can we pick specific word documents in these folders and convert them to pdf?

```
Sub BatchConvertDocxToPDF()
  Dim objDoc As Document
  Dim strFile As String, strFolder As String
 
  'Initialization
  strFolder = "C:\Users\Test\Desktop\Test Files\"
  strFile = Dir(strFolder & "*.docx", vbNormal)
 
  'Precess each file in the file folder and convert them to pdf.
  While strFile <> ""
    Set objDoc = Documents.Open(FileName:=strFolder & strFile)
 
    objDoc.ExportAsFixedFormat _
      OutputFileName:=Replace(objDoc.FullName, ".docx", ".pdf"), _
      ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF, OpenAfterExport:=False, OptimizeFor:=wdExportOptimizeForPrint, _
      Range:=wdExportAllDocument, Item:=wdExportDocumentContent
 
    objDoc.Close
    strFile = Dir()
  Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: There are several questions on here on how to "Loop Through All Subfolders", so just search for that and you should get a couple of ways to do it. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9827715/get-list-of-sub-directories-in-vba) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14245712/cycle-through-sub-folders-and-files-in-a-user-specified-root-directory) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22645347/loop-through-all-subfolders-using-vba). And if you want to pick something specific, then just speciy that instead of the current "all" `While strFile <> ""`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cycle through sub-folders and files in a user-specified root directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14245712/cycle-through-sub-folders-and-files-in-a-user-specified-root-directory)

Comment: See the second part of https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/MacrosVBA/BatchFR.htm about using  the FileSearch object instead of Dir. That page is about find and replace but the same method could be used for saving as pdf.