# Loop through files in a folder, exclude the last file

Tags: vba, powerpoint

i have a folder that has the structure of subfolders filled with powerpoints and one powerpoint outside of those subfolders, so kind of like this:

```
[main folder]
 |-[subfolder 1]
   |-ppt A
 |-[subfolder 2]
   |-ppt B
 |-ppt file to exclude
```

my goal is to loop through these subfolders, perform actions on the powerpoints inside the subfolders, and ignore the ppt at the end. i can't hardcode the name of the ppt because the name gets updated every week with a new date in the title. is this possible to do without hardcoding the file name?

while simply testing, i've tried using a do-while loop and hardcoded the name, but that didn't seem to work. in fact, i think it ended up running an endless loop and crashed my PPT:

```
  Dim File
    For Each File In Folder.Files
        Debug.Print File.path
        
        Do While File <> "hardcoded file name"
            If Right(File, 5) Like ".ppt*" Then
                Set objPresentation = Presentations.Open(File, msoFalse, msoFalse, msoFalse)
                For i = 1 To 1
                    objPresentation.Slides.Item(1).Copy
                    Presentations.Item(1).Slides.Paste
                    Presentations.Item(1).Slides.Item(Presentations.Item(1).Slides.Count).Design = _
                        objPresentation.Slides.Item(1).Design
                    ActivePresentation.Slides(ActiveWindow.View.Slide.SlideIndex).Shapes("Rectangle 2").Delete
                 Next i
                 objPresentation.Close
            End If
        Loop
    Next
    
End Sub
```

i thought about using a case statement, but wasn't exactly sure where to place it. even if i were to get it to work, i'm not sure if it would still work without the file name being hardcoded.

Comment: Does it also crash if you remove parts of those inner loops? What is the goal of `for i = 1 to 1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're only interested in files in subfolders, then something like this will only give you those paths:

```vb
Sub Tester()
    Dim f As Object, sf As Object, fl As Object
    
    Set f = CreateObject("Scripting.Filesystemobject").getfolder("C:\Temp\VBA")
    'only check subfolders
    For Each sf In f.subfolders
        Debug.Print sf.Name
        'loop files in subfolder
        For Each f In sf.Files
            If LCase(f.Name) Like "*.ppt*" Then
                Debug.Print , f.Path
            End If
        Next f
    Next sf
End Sub
```

Comment: this is great, but it seems to have created an endless loop for me and it just goes back to the first subfolder. how can i end it once it gets to the last subfolder? thank you!

Comment: It's not an endless loop as posted, so did you make some changes?

Comment: i did, but actually just came back to say that i fixed it and to disregard. thank you for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

To identify the last file in your start folder, you can use File's property `count`:

```
Dim counter As Long
counter = folder.Files.Count
   
For Each file In folder.Files
  counter = counter - 1
  If counter = 0 Then Debug.Print "Last one"
  Debug.Print file.Path
Next file
```

To search the subfolders see other answers, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14246818/17017616)