Redim Array for ListBox
I'm parsing folders & subfolders for certain files with text in them and getting the results returned, but I keep getting "error 380 could not set the list property". I Redimemd my confList array to match the File results but can't see what I'm missing. Any help is appreciated!
Sub searchConf(Folder)
    Dim SubFolder
    Dim File
    Dim confList()
    Dim searchFullName As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim FSO As Object
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        
    i = 0
        
    searchFullName = dwgText1.Value
    
    For Each SubFolder In Folder.SubFolders
        searchConf SubFolder
        If SubFolder.Name Like searchFullName Then
            i = i + 1
            ReDim confList(1 To SubFolder.Files.Count, 1 To 3)
            For Each File In SubFolder.Files
                confList(i, 1) = File.Name
                confList(i, 2) = FSO.GetExtensionName(LCase(File))
                confList(i, 3) = File.path
            Next
        End If
    Next
        
    With list2
        .Clear
        .ColumnCount = 2
        .ColumnWidths = "146;20"
        .List = confList
    End With
    
    If list2.List(0) = "" Then
        With list2
            .Clear
            .AddItem "NO FILES FOUND"
        End With
    End If
    
End Sub

The above Sub is called from:
Sub getConf()
    Dim FileSystem As Object
    Dim dataSplit() As String
    Dim firstFolder, searchFullName As String
    
    searchFullName = dwgText1.Value
    
    dataSplit = Split(searchFullName, "-")
    firstFolder = dataSplit(0)
    
    folderName = folderName & "\" & firstFolder
        
    Set FileSystem = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    searchConf FileSystem.GetFolder(folderName)

End Sub

I tried what you suggested but still getting the "308 error, could not set the list property". I confirmed the file count in the folder and that they were results from the for loop:
If Folder.Files.Count <> 0 Then
    ReDim confList(1 To Folder.Files.Count, 1 To 3)
End If

For Each SubFolder In Folder.SubFolders
    searchConf SubFolder
    If SubFolder.Name Like searchFullName Then
        Debug.Print SubFolder.Files.Count
        ReDim confList(1 To SubFolder.Files.Count, 1 To 3)
        i = i + 1
        For Each File In SubFolder.Files
            confList(i, 1) = File.Name
            confList(i, 2) = FSO.GetExtensionName(LCase(File))
            confList(i, 3) = File.path
        Next
    End If
Next
    
With list2
    .Clear
    .ColumnCount = 2
    .ColumnWidths = "146;20"
    .List = confList
End With

It generates the error at the ".List = confList" line. Am I not calling the array correctly there or is the problem with the array itself?

What language is it? VB?

VBA, my apologies for for not adding that.

What is Folder? First you need GetFolder(Folder) if the Sub argument is a string.

ReDim is extremely inefficient. GetFolder() is supposed to return a Collection of Folder objects, which should have a Count property you can use to set the initial size for confList once. But if that doesn't work, it's still more efficient to iterate over the collection twice, just to get the count the first time, than to do it once with a ReDim inside the loop.

You have sequencing problems in your code on scrolling through subfolders and do something if found. First have a look e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14245712/cycle-through-sub-folders-and-files-in-a-user-specified-root-directory. There you can find other references how to loop through subfolders.
