# Excel VBA using FileSystemObject to list file last date modified

Tags: vba

this is my first time asking question so hopefully I'm following protocol.
This is in reference to "get list of subdirs in vba" [get list of subdirs in vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9827715/get-list-of-subdirs-in-vba).

I found Brett's example #1 - Using FileScriptingObject most helpful. But there's one more data element (DateLastModified) I need in results. I tried to modify the code but keep getting invalid qualifier error. Here are code modifications I made:

1. Range("A1:C1") = Array("File Name", "Path", "Date Last Modified").
2. Do While loop added this => Cells(i, 3) = myFile.DateLastModified.

Will appreciate help to include the "Date Last Modified".

Santosh here is complete code with comments indicating modifications.

```
Public Arr() As String
Public Counter As Long

Sub LoopThroughFilePaths()
Dim myArr
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim MyFile As String
Const strPath As String = "c:\temp\"
myArr = GetSubFolders(strPath)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'Range("A1:B1") = Array("text file", "path")' <= orig code
Range("A1:C1") = Array("text file", "path", "Date Last Modified") ' <= modified code
    For j = LBound(Arr) To UBound(Arr)
        MyFile = Dir(myArr(j) & "\*.txt")
        Do While Len(MyFile) <> 0
        i = i + 1
            Cells(i, 1) = MyFile
            Cells(i, 2) = myArr(j)
            Cells(i, 3) = MyFile.DateLastModified ' <= added to modify code
            MyFile = Dir
        Loop
    Next j
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Function GetSubFolders(RootPath As String)
Dim fso As Object
Dim fld As Object
Dim sf As Object
Dim myArr

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set fld = fso.GetFolder(RootPath)
For Each sf In fld.SubFolders
    Counter = Counter + 1
    ReDim Preserve Arr(Counter)
    Arr(Counter) = sf.Path
    myArr = GetSubFolders(sf.Path)
Next
GetSubFolders = Arr
Set sf = Nothing
Set fld = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: Can u put the complete code along with changes you made ?

Comment: Santosh below is complete code along with modifications

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this code :

```
Sub ListFilesinFolder()

    Dim FSO As Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Dim SourceFolder As Scripting.Folder
    Dim FileItem As Scripting.File

    SourceFolderName = "C:\Users\Santosh"

    Set FSO = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Set SourceFolder = FSO.GetFolder(SourceFolderName)

    Range("A1:C1") = Array("text file", "path", "Date Last Modified")

    i = 2
    For Each FileItem In SourceFolder.Files
        Cells(i, 1) = FileItem.Name
        Cells(i, 2) = FileItem
        Cells(i, 3) = FileItem.DateLastModified
        i = i + 1
    Next FileItem

    Set FSO = Nothing

End Sub
```