# Find last save time of a closed workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to make a macro that can reference when another workbook was last updated without opening it.

I found this one but it only works on the active workbook:

```
Function LastModified() as Date

  LastModified = ActiveWorkbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties("Last Save Time")

End Function
```

What I want is something like this:

```
Function LastModified() as Date

  LastModified = path."c:/test.xlsx".BuiltinDocumentProperties("Last Save Time")

End Function
```

But that didn't work of course. How do I fix this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16627441/excel-vba-using-filesystemobject-to-list-file-last-date-modified

Comment: Wouldn't `FileDateTime` suffice for that?

Comment: VBA does not support reading from closed documents.  If you want to access built-in properties from a closed document, you will need to install the MS supplied DLL file called DSO OLE Document Properties Reader 2.1.  See Chip Pearsons page on [Document Properties](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/docprop.aspx).  Or you can use the `FileSystemObject` to access the `LastModified` time.  Whether that will provide the same information as the built-in property is not known to me.  But perhaps the result will be sufficient (and it is simpler to implement).

Answer (score 1):

The Filesystemobject worked but I needed then to print it to cells, as it would'nt call the function.

The FileDateTime worked for me though :)

```
Function LastModified() as Date

  LastModified = FileDateTime("filepath")

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the trick. You'll need to use the `FileSystemObject` in this example. I'm using late binding in the example, but you may get some performance improvements if you switch to early binding.

```
Option Explicit

Private Function LastModified(ByRef filePath As String) As Date
    'Set a default value
    LastModified = vbNull

    If Len(Trim$(filePath)) = 0 Then Exit Function

    With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        If .FileExists(filePath) Then LastModified = .GetFile(filePath).DateLastModified
    End With

End Function

Sub SOExample()
    'Specify a path to a file you want to get LastModified Date
    Dim filePath As String: filePath = "MyPathToAFile"

    'Return a date or vbNull
    Dim myDate As Date: myDate = LastModified(filePath)

    'Output the Date if it isn't vbNull
    If Not myDate = vbNull Then Debug.Print myDate
End Sub
```