# List files in folder and subfolder with path to .txt file

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel sheet that has a cell that contains the path to a directory, i want a macro that searches the directory and any sub directories and lists the files in a .txt file, with the full path of each file.

This is currently what i have found that looks like it should find the files except the path is hard-coded and it doesn't do anything with the results.

Any ideas how i can change it to fit my needs?

```
Sub LoopThroughFiles()
Dim StrFile As String
StrFile = Dir("C:\Work\NCL\nCLs\histogram_addition\TestData\Input\RTE\")
Do While Len(StrFile) > 0
    Debug.Print StrFile
    StrFile = Dir
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9827715/get-list-of-subdirs-in-vba

Comment: Change `Dir("C:\Work\NCL\nCLs\histogram_addition\TestData\Input\RTE\")` to `Dir(Range("A1").Value)` (modify to the correct cell reference.  This code prints the results in the Immediate pane in the VBE. You could modify it to create a text file and print each path to a new line in the file.

Comment: I'm new to VBA just checked the immediate pane and its empty, any ideas why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a method cobbled together from the FileSystemObject() examples using a recursive call. Apply a sort to the results if needed. You can also filter by .txt extension using other FileSystemObject() methods:

```
    Sub Sample()
        ShowFolderList ("C:\temp")
    End Sub

    Sub ShowFolderList(folderspec)
        Dim fs, f, f1, fc, s, sFldr
        Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        Set f = fs.GetFolder(folderspec)
        Set fc = f.SubFolders
         For Each f1 In fc
            If Right(f1, 1) <> "\" Then ShowFolderList f1 & "\" Else ShowFolderList f1
        Next
        Set fc = f.Files
        For Each f1 In fc
            Debug.Print folderspec & f1.Name
        Next
    End Sub
```

Write to file:

```
    Option Explicit

    Dim file As Object
    Dim fs As Object

    Sub go()
        Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        Set file = fs.OpenTextFile("C:\temp2\results3.txt", 2, True) ' 2=ForWriting, replace
        ShowFolderList "C:\temp\"
        file.Close
        MsgBox "done"
    End Sub

    Sub ShowFolderList(folderspec)
    On Error GoTo local_err
        Dim f, f1, fc, s, sFldr
        Set f = fs.GetFolder(folderspec)
        Set fc = f.SubFolders
         For Each f1 In fc
            If Right(f1, 1) <> "\" Then ShowFolderList f1 & "\" Else ShowFolderList f1
        Next
        Set fc = f.Files
        For Each f1 In fc
            file.writeline folderspec & f1.Name
        Next
     local_exit:
        Exit Sub
     local_err:
        MsgBox Err & " " & Err.Description
        Resume local_exit
        Resume
    End Sub
```

Comment: That works spot on thanks. How do i get that to print to a text file

Comment: It is worth learning how to use FileSystemObject(). You can add a reference to Windows Scripting Runtime to enable intellisense.

Comment: Thanks I've still got a lot to learn when it comes to vba, unfortunately I don't get much time to investigate. fingers crossed this will change soon. Thanks for help

Comment: + 1 :) I have edited your code. `Go` is a reserved word and sometimes when the sub is run, will give you an error message `Expected "To"`.