# How to list files in VBA with long paths?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using FileSystemObject to loop from files in folder, but I found that in some cases I'm missing files.

I have a folder with 20 files and when trying to list them I only see 14. The path is very long, so it seems to skip the files with >250 characters long.

```
Sub CountFilesInFolder()
   
    Dim xFileSystemObject As Object
    Dim xFolder As Object
    Dim xFile As Object
    Dim countx As Long
    Dim xFolderName As String
    Dim rowIndex As Long
    
    xFolderName = "\\server\[long folder name]"
     
    Set xFileSystemObject = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set xFolder = xFileSystemObject.GetFolder(xFolderName)
    
    For Each xFile In xFolder.Files
        rowIndex = rowIndex + 1
        Application.ActiveSheet.Cells(rowIndex, 1).Formula = xFile.Name
    Next
    
End Sub
```

Is there any other way to extract the list of files (and information from the files) using vba?

I tried both methods from another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33887223/list-all-files-in-a-folder-and-subfolders-in-excel), but I got the same problem

Comment: Some of the solutions on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2516702/6706419) may be of interest

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access files with long paths (over 260)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38432250/access-files-with-long-paths-over-260)

Answer (score 0):

```
'use short name instead and check if all your files are listed

xFile.ShortName
```

Comment: please no code only answer