# Move files from multiple folders to a single folder

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to consolidate Excel files from different folders to a single folder. Within each folder there is a single Excel file.

```vb
Sub move_data()

Dim FSO As Object
Dim FromPath As String
Dim ToPath As String
Dim Fdate As Date
Dim FileInFromFolder As Object

MkDir "C:\User\TEST\"        
FromPath = "C:\User\MainFolder\" 
ToPath = "C:\User\TEST\"     
    
Set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")

If FSO.FolderExists(FromPath) = False Then
    MsgBox FromPath & " doesn't exist"
    Exit Sub
End If

For Each FileInFromFolder In FSO.GetFolder(FromPath).Files
    FileInFromFolder.Move ToPath
Next FileInFromFolder

End Sub
```

The code is unable to get the files from the subfolder within the folder (as shown in the image).

The area I am looking to change is 'FromPath', if it is possible to include a wildcard to specify the subfolders?

Multiple Folders, One Excel file per Folder
[image]

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68246938/get-file-list-from-folders-and-subfolders-excel-vba) will help you to loop trough folders and subfolders. Just adapt it to move only Excel files

Answer (score 2):

### Move Files From Multiple Folders to Single Folder (`FileSystemObject`)

```vb
Sub MoveFiles()

    Const FromPath As String = "C:\MainFolder\"
    Const ToPath As String = "C:\Test\"
    Const LCaseExtensionPattern As String = "xls*"
    
    Dim fso As Object: Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    
    If Not fso.FolderExists(FromPath) Then
        MsgBox "The folder '" & FromPath & "' doesn't exist.", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    If Not fso.FolderExists(ToPath) Then MkDir ToPath
    
    Dim SubFolderPaths() As String: SubFolderPaths = ArrSubFolderPaths(FromPath)
    
    Dim fsoFile As Object
    Dim NotMoved() As String
    Dim n As Long
    Dim mCount As Long
    Dim nmCount As Long
    
    For n = 0 To UBound(SubFolderPaths)
        For Each fsoFile In fso.GetFolder(SubFolderPaths(n)).Files
            If LCase(fso.GetExtensionName(fsoFile)) _
                    Like LCaseExtensionPattern Then
                If Not fso.FileExists(ToPath & fsoFile.Name) Then
                    mCount = mCount + 1
                    fsoFile.Move ToPath
                Else
                    nmCount = nmCount + 1
                    ReDim Preserve NotMoved(1 To nmCount)
                    NotMoved(nmCount) = fsoFile.Path
                End If
            End If
        Next fsoFile
    Next n
 
    Dim MsgString As String
    MsgString = "Files moved: " & mCount & "(" & mCount + nmCount & ")"
    If nmCount > 0 Then
        MsgString = MsgString & vbLf & vbLf & "Files not moved: " & mCount _
            & "(" & mCount + nmCount & "):" & vbLf & vbLf & Join(NotMoved, vbLf)
    End If
    
    MsgBox MsgString, vbInformation
    
End Sub


Function ArrSubFolderPaths( _
    ByVal InitialFolderPath As String, _
    Optional ByVal ExcludeInitialFolderPath As Boolean = False) _
As String()
    Const ProcName As String = "ArrSubFolderPaths"
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    
    ' Ensure that a string array is passed if an error occurs.
    Dim Arr() As String: Arr = Split("") ' LB = 0 , UB = -1
    
    ' Locate the trailing path separator.
    Dim pSep As String: pSep = Application.PathSeparator
    If Right(InitialFolderPath, 1) <> pSep Then
        InitialFolderPath = InitialFolderPath & pSep
    End If
    
    ' Add the initial folder path to a new collection.
    Dim fso As Object: Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Dim coll As Collection: Set coll = New Collection
    coll.Add fso.GetFolder(InitialFolderPath)
    
    ' Add the initial folder path (or don't) to the result.
    Dim n As Long
    If ExcludeInitialFolderPath Then ' don't add
        n = -1
    Else ' add
        ReDim Preserve Arr(0 To 0): Arr(0) = coll(1)
    End If
    
    Dim fsoFolder As Object
    Dim fsoSubFolder As Object
    
    Do While coll.Count > 0
        Set fsoFolder = coll(1)
        coll.Remove 1
        For Each fsoSubFolder In fsoFolder.SubFolders
            coll.Add fsoSubFolder
            n = n + 1: ReDim Preserve Arr(0 To n): Arr(n) = fsoSubFolder
        Next fsoSubFolder
    Loop

    ArrSubFolderPaths = Arr

ProcExit:
    Exit Function
ClearError:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "' Run-time error '" _
        & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf & "    " & Err.Description
    Resume ProcExit
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This code works and it helped to copy all of the Excel files from the subfolder. Are we able to make a slight tweak to the code to only grab this specific file named 'DPP General Template Day X Block A.xlsx'? Where Day X changes based on the folder date. E.g. 'Day 13' for the folder '13.11.2021'

Comment: After the `If LCase... Then` line, add another `If` statement: `If Instr(1, fsoFile.Name, "DPP General Template Day", vbTextCompare) = 1 Then` (i.e. begins with). and don't forget the 'closing' `End If`.

Answer (score 1):

This is simple to achieve if you adopt recursive procedure.

```
Sub Starter()
    Call FilesMover("C:\User\MainFolder\", "C:\User\TEST\")
End Sub

Sub FilesMover(FromPath As String, DestinationPath As String)
    Dim fso As object
    Set fso = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
    Dim f As File
    Dim d As Folder
    
    ' first move the files in the folder
    For Each f In fso.GetFolder(FromPath).Files
        f.Move DestinationPath
    Next f
    
    ' then check the subfolders
    For Each d In fso.GetFolder(FromPath).SubFolders
        Call FilesMover(d.Path, DestinationPath)
    Next d
End Sub
```

Comment: This works! Thank you so much! But are you to advise on how we can further edit the code so to move a specific Excel file? Within the folder there are multiple Excel files and I am just looking to move a single file. Say the file name is  'DPP General Template Day X Block A.xlsx'? Where Day X changes based on the folder date. E.g. 'Day 13' for the folder '13.11.2021'

Comment: @JeremyWong you can use the `If..Else..End If` to move files conditionally. You can refer this doc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/using-ifthenelse-statements. The file name get be obtained using `f.name`