# to use name of array as parameter in for next cycle

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, for-loop, arraylist

in excel VBA (macro) i try to parametrize "for-next" cycle for work with arrays. I need to repaetedly  create a list of folders in variable locations. this is code:

```
Sub create_DD_folders()
' create folders

Dim fso
Dim myBaseDir1 As String, myBaseDir2 As String, myDir1 As String, myDir2 As String, myWholeDir
Dim foldersList1 As Variant, foldersList2 As Variant, foldersList As Variant, folder As Variant, sHostName As String
Dim i As Integer


    
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    
    'folders for disc C
    foldersList1 = Array("form", "folderA1", "folderAB", "folderAC")
    
    'folders for disc D  
    foldersList2 = Array("form", "folderB1", "folderBB", "folderYC")
    
    myBaseDir1 = ("c:\Dokumenty\Work\Project\")
    myBaseDir2 = ("d:\My_disc\Projects\")
        
        myDir1 = myBaseDir1 & "\" & "abc" & "-" & "xyz"    ' abc and xyz are variables unimportant for example 
        myDir2 = myBaseDir1 & "\" & "abc" & "-" & "xyz"
    
    For i = 1 To 2
        If Not fso.FolderExists("myDir" & i) Then MkDir ("myDir" & i)
            foldersList = "floldersList" & i     ' this row give error 13 (type Mismatch) 
                For Each folder In foldersList
                   myWholeDir = "myDir" & i & "\" & Slozka
                       If Not fso.FolderExists(myWholeDir) Then MkDir (myWholeDir)
                Next folder
    Next i
    
End Sub
```

Please give me a help

i need to create a folders from folders lists using for-next cycle or more efectively.

Comment: Use a `Scripting.Dictionary`.

Comment: Also have a look at [this question about folders with subfolders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9827715/get-list-of-sub-directories-in-vba)

Comment: What is Slozka?  a variable or a literal "Slozka"
Is that you want to create?
c:\Dokumenty\Work\Project\abc-xyz

c:\Dokumenty\Work\Project\abc-xyz\form\Slozka

c:\Dokumenty\Work\Project\abc-xyz\folderA1\Slozka

c:\Dokumenty\Work\Project\abc-xyz\folderAB\Slozka

c:\Dokumenty\Work\Project\abc-xyz\folderAC\Slozka

d:\My_disc\Projects\abc-xyz

d:\My_disc\Projects\abc-xyz\form\Slozka

d:\My_disc\Projects\abc-xyz\folderB1\Slozka

d:\My_disc\Projects\abc-xyz\folderBB\Slozka

d:\My_disc\Projects\abc-xyz\folderYC\Slozka