VBA Code How to get muiltiple Folder path
On Exce, I want to store the paths of folders in an array (I have a sample code I made), but I can't select multiple folders even though I've used .AllowMultiSelect = True. Is there a solution or any suggestions?
Sub SelectMultipleFolders() 
    Dim selectedFolders As FileDialog 
    Dim folderPath As Variant 
      
    Set selectedFolders = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker) 
    selectedFolders.AllowMultiSelect = True 
     
    If selectedFolders.Show = -1 Then 
        For Each folderPath In selectedFolders.SelectedItems 
            MsgBox "Selected Folder: " & folderPath 
        Next folderPath 
    Else 
        MsgBox "Not selected." 
    End If 
End Sub

I want to store the paths in multiple variables.

.AllowMultiSelect only applies to selecting files. AFAIK, there is no support for multiple selection of folders.

I think the best solution would be to use a two step approach implemented in a Userform. Step 1: a text box with a button that asks for the root folder. Step 2 a multi-select list box which shows all child folders of the folder selected in step 1.

See @brettdj solutions at:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9827715/get-list-of-sub-directories-in-vba
(not enough rep to post as comment) :(

I don't think it can be done with the built in file dialog box.  All I can think of it picking one at a time but it's a pretty awkward solution:
Sub SelectMultipleFolders()
    Dim selectedFolders As FileDialog
    Dim folderPath As String
    Dim folderPaths() As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim proceed As Boolean
    
    Set selectedFolders = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    
    i = 0
    proceed = True
    
    Do While proceed
        If selectedFolders.Show = -1 Then
            
            ReDim Preserve folderPaths(i)
            folderPaths(i) = selectedFolders.SelectedItems(1)
            MsgBox "Selected Folder: " & folderPaths(i)
            i = i + 1
            
            
            If MsgBox("Do you want to select another folder?", vbYesNo) = vbNo Then
                proceed = False
            End If
        Else
            MsgBox "Folder selection canceled."
            proceed = False
        End If
    Loop
    
    
    If i > 0 Then
        MsgBox "Total folders selected: " & UBound(folderPaths) + 1
        For i = LBound(folderPaths) To UBound(folderPaths)
            MsgBox "Folder " & i + 1 & ": " & folderPaths(i)
        Next i
    End If
End Sub

